List of most unanswered tags
Just thought I'd post this because it's interesting, this is a list of most unanswered tags:

To me it looks like there is a relationship of difficulty to unanswered questions. BLDC  power-electronics and EMC questions would be the hardest to solve because of the complexity of the design and the time it takes to find the issue.

Does "unanswered" mean the question does not have an accepted answer, or does it mean the question has 0 answers?

In case of more advanced questions on these topics, I think most of them require specialized knowledge to answer. Not strange that they are the least answered ones.

@toolic no answers

Sounds like topics that someone with the name Voltage Spike should be able to answer!

Are any of the "unanswered" questions explained by the question getting closed? E.g. due to  "Needs details or clarity".

You can check each tag to see what percentage are closed or spot check it.

Most of the BLDC tags are open
